# Php If statement, to return set values from CMB2

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm having trouble trying to find an answer to create a simple If statment that will return the html code I set if the values are entered within the backend of the page.

for example;

I want to display this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_mo_youtube_link', true ); ?>" class="product-yuotube" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i> Watch Video</a>
```

but ONLY if the feild is filled in within the back of wordpress. I dont really know what else to say but if you require some more information then id answer any questions.

Thanks

Comment: Few things are unclear:- where is if condition? where you want to put that? what is the response of `get_post_meta` function? also post your expected output.

Comment: Hi Mate, So im using CMB2 within the back-end. I dont have an if condition as I dont know how to start one.

The output I need to display is what I have posted above, I just need the if statement around that.

Comment: Here is the function that it uses. 

 $cmb_homepage->add_field( array(
  'name'       => __( 'YouTube Link', 'cmb2' ),
  'desc'       => __( 'url', 'cmb2' ),
  'id'         => $prefix . 'youtube_link',
  'type'    => 'text'
 ) );